# Is StreamPartitioner in Kafka-streams thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm building simple kafka-streams application.I need to use multiple number of threads and custom StreamPartitioner:

```
props.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG, "3");

Partitioner partitioner = new Partitioner();
textLines.to(OUT_TOPIC, Produced.streamPartitioner(partitioner));
```

can I be sure that different threads will use their own partitioner instance?
If not, how can i perform it?

Answer (score 0):

No. The created partitioner instance would be shared over all threads.

Usually, partitioners are stateless and thus, sharing the instance is not an issue. If you do have shared state, you would need to implement the class in a thread safe manner.

As an alternative, it should be possible to configure the producer's partitioner directly, by setting `partitioner.class` config on the `StreamsConfig`.